# Read and manipulate objects from another module [Python + Maya]

Tags: python, maya, python-module

Thank you for your patience, I'm not a great coder but I would try to do my best simplifying all my rigging stuff.
I searched everywhere on the net, if I'm asking right now it's because I clearly can't understand somewhat.

I'm creating an auto-rigger tool and I'm declaring some curves in *main.py*.
Actually I created a particular curve with more than seventy CVs and so, in *main.py*, I have this thing long about twenty rows. Navigate what I wrote is becoming awful.
So, for now, I want to have a better order moving this object in another module called *UI_library.py*.

In *UI_library.py* I declared some function to access my clavController object.

```
.../UI_library.py

def createClav():
        clavController = cmds.curve(d=1, p=[coordinates])
```

In *main.py* I call the func.

```
.../main.py

import UI_library as libs
clavController = libs.createClav()
```

The *newClav* curve is generated in my Maya scene and when I execute

```
print(newClav)
```

The result is *none* and at this point I'm stuck because I can't use the curve I built

Should I create global var between files? Learn and use classes? I thought this would be a simple work of "translation".
Thank you again

Comment: You're not returning anything in `createClav`